# How to send message/data from broadcast receiver (process1) to Service thread (process2) in android?

Tags: android, ipc, android-broadcast

I am developing an android application. This application architecture is divided into 5 modules with 2 modules having multiple features. To develop this app, I am creating 2 process with multiple threads in them as required and 3 other threads. I have a some questions regarding this implementation:

Is this a good model? If not, why not? Right now I am considering only modularity.

I need to send a message from broadcast receiver in process1 to Service thread in process2, what is the best way to do it?

what is the best IPC mechanism in android? I tried to use this link, http://androidapps.org.ua/androidintro_ipc_intent.html which suggests startActivity and startActivityForResult, but these options are not available in broadcast receiver and service does not have startActivityForResult option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use Custom `BroadcastReceiver`

Write this in **ActivityA.java**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.putExtra("message","hi");
 intent.setAction("com.android.activity.SEND_DATA");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Write this in **ServiceA.java**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // Extract data included in the Intent
   String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
   Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};
```

Now register `Receiver`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
  new IntentFilter("com.android.activity.SEND_DATA"));
```

Comment: Hey Rstar, I need to send a message from Broadcastreceiver's onReceive function to a service and they are located on different services. I can do the latter part i.e. create another Broadcast receiver in service. But for the first part I do not see the option, sendBroadcast in Broadcastreceiver's onReceive function.

Comment: You don't want to send a broadcast intent just to pass data to a service. You can do this directly.

Comment: @DavidWasser is right if you don't want to use BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @Rstar Can I send Broadcast from service instead of activity. or else do I have to make changes in sendBroadcast .
if yes then this is Exactly what I was Looking for

Answer (score 1):

Just create an `Intent` in the `BroadcastReceiver`, add your data as extras, can call `startService()` with the `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("message", "whatever data you need to pass to the service");
context.startService(intent);
```

The method `onStartCommand()` will be called in your service with the passed `Intent`.

To answer your other question "what is the best IPC method", the answer (as always) is "that depends". Using `Intent`s is the easiest method, as it is supported for all components out-of-the-box. If you need more complicated interaction between components you can look at using AIDL which will allow you to do remote method calls in a `Service`. If that still isn't enough, then just implement your own socket protocol between the 2 components.

Comment: David, One more question, let us say I am trying to send data/message to activity (not service) in another process, how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, you call `startService()` on the `context` parameter in `onReceive()`. I fixed my code.

Comment: If you want to send data/message to an activity, you do it exactly the same way. You create an `Intent`, add your data as extras and call `context.startActivity()`. You can start an activity in any process (in fact, when you start an activity, you really don't have any idea or control over what process it will be started in).

Comment: yeah, but what if it the activity is already running? sudhee answered my question i.e. to use flags.

Comment: If activity is already running, the default behaviour would be to create another instance of that activity. However, if you use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` or if the activity is defined with `launchMode="singleTop"` then the `Intent` will be delivered to the existing activity using `onNewIntent()`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, trying to understand your terminologies.  By process, I presume you mean activity and "service thread", I presume you mean a service.

If you want to send a message from onReceive() broadcast receiver, running in context of Activity 1, to a service which is already active, you can try one of the below:

1) Create a new intent (service class name as the class) and call startService() with the intent. Add the additional parameters you need as intent extras.  It does not matter if your service is already active, the onStartCommand() is still called,  you can have special parameters as intent extras to differentiate a onStartCommand() from onReceive.

2) If your scenario allows this, consider registering to same broadcast event in both your activity and service and act appropriately (then no need to pass messages)

3) Write another broadcast receiver in your service and call sendBroadcast() from the Activity's broadcast receiver

Comment: No, process does not mean activity and yes service thread I meant service. I dont see startService and sendBroadcast options in Broadcastreceiver's onReceive function. Eclipse says these methods do not exist, implement them. I did not understand option 2.

Comment: Do you have manifest defined Broadcast Receiver or a dynamically registered receiver ?

Comment: Dynamically registered using registerReceiver(localFaultDetector, batteryLifeFilter); this method.

Comment: use the context passed as parameter1 of onReceive() ex: arg0.startActivity() or arg0.sendBroadcast()

Comment: clarity on option 2: I meant that you register to the same broadcast event in both your "process" and the service with onReceive() coded in both.  You will receive the broadcast in both places.  However, in case you need some additional processing in your "process" before passing it on to your service, this will not work.

Comment: thank you sudhee... :( I kept trying with Context. or Context(). and it didn't work. with context it works. btw, how to send if the receiver is not service but an activity.

Comment: You can use same methods on activities also, but startActivity will start new instance of the activity, if activity already exists, use flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT(or FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP as your case is) to bring it to front.

Comment: Thanks, that was the confusion.